# Inner working of Integer('string') call?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

If I want to see if a string is a valid integer, I can do:

```
puts Integer('1') #=> 1
```

as any non-integer would raise an error:

```
puts Integer('a') #=> invalid value for Integer(): "a" (ArgumentError)
```

If I want to make sure my variable is both a Float and an Integer, I do not want to repeat myself so I try to put the classes in a list:

```
x = '1'
[Integer, Float].each{|c| puts c(x) } #=> undefined method `c' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Will someone explain why this does not work, and if there is some way to achieve what I am looking for? What kind of method call is `Integer(var)`?

Note, I have no real world problem I'm trying to solve here, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
Integer('10')
```

you are essentially calling the [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) class method defined in [`Kernel`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html), passing it the argument `10`.

To achieve what you want you can do:

```
[:Integer, :Float].each { |c| puts method(c).call(x) }
```

Comment: Another way: `[:Integer, :Float].each{ |c| puts send(c, x) }`